# Is it possible to display the date/time in Vim (over Putty)?

Tags: linux, vim, date, time

I am looking at logs with Vim. Frequently I need to compare with the current date/time.
Each time I have exit the editor to look at the clock and return.
Is there some way to configure Vim to have the server date/time always visible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Status line with current date and time:

```
set rulerformat=%55(%{strftime('%a\ %b\ %e\ %I:%M\ %p')}\ %5l,%-6(%c%V%)\ %P%)
```

[Source](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Display_date-and-time_on_status_line)

And interestingly, the time gets updated whenever there is an activity !

Comment: Excellent: time stands still whilst one is thoughtfully staring at the screen!

Comment: you also need to do :set ruler

Answer (score 9):

if you are on unix like environment `:!date` is easiest to look at clock.

Answer (score 6):

You could just call the `date` utility like よすけさばい (yosukesabai*) suggested, however that causes the standard "Hit ENTER to continue" prompt to appear. I'd go with:

```
:echo system("date")
```

Seems a bit neater. Then you can also create a map:

```
:nnoremap ,d :echo system("date")<CR>
```

And check the date easily with `,d`. The other alternative is including that in your ruler or status bar (if you have it always displayed) as others already posted, however that's not my personal taste :-)

* <sup>*I hope it's written correctly*</sup>

Answer (score 2):

As well as escaping to the shell and running the `date` command as [yosukesabai said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065777/does-possibly-that-vim-putty-displays-date-time/8065799#8065799), you can add these lines to your .vimrc (on the remote machine, in your case):

```
set ruler
set rulerformat=%55(%{strftime('%a\ %b\ %e\ %I:%M\ %p')}\ %5l,%-6(%c%V%)\ %P%)
```

Now when you open a file with Vim, the current date and time are displayed at the bottom of the editor. The time will update whenever you type anything in the editor. This tip is described on [the Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Display_date-and-time_on_status_line).